# Trying to implement MUC Chat in Openfire and Android using Smack

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, multiuserchat

Groups are created using MUC, but i cannot retrieve all group of user.  I have done research  and This is deprecated and REST API is recommended. The REST API is  not working as expected. I am not able to  connect to server. I have added REST API plugin. Now in my android code I have set the secret key but not able to connect to localhost openfire server.

Help needed

Comment: What is the response from the REST API you get on your phone?

Comment: I am trying this url in postman http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms/ . I have set headers  values "Content-Type":"application/json"   and "Authorization":"MF9mRzGQKL3O5ipz". This key I got after installing the REST API plugin through setting and checking secret key  mode.   paramater passed are      naturalName, roomName, description  with values.  Result I am getting is Status: 403 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Rest API plugin, it is not enabled per default. You can enable the plugin on the same page where you saw the secret key (Server Settings tab). That's why you get 403 Forbidden and not 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Let me check it and then I will get back